# How to add middle URL to Exoplayer builder before server auto redirecting to m3u8 file?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

In Node.js server, I have an api test.com/song/stream. When send request to this api, it will do some logic task and redirect to api test.com/song/abc.m3u8. In android, I use media3 lib and HLS service:

```
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this.requireActivity().applicationContext).build() binding.videoView.player = exoPlayer
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(
            MediaItem.fromUri(
                "test.com/song/stream"
            )
```

Now I run the code and get exception "androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error".

I wonder how to add a middle http request to get right URI to the m3u8 file, but this is auto task done by server, android client cannot control this.